# cannot update 10.04 server

Tags: 10.04, server, apt, lts

I've tried to update 10.04.3 Server but I get an error (sorry but trey're written in slovene) says that cannot download updates and cannot connect to  http://si.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried an apt-get update before the install?  Stale local database questions pop up all the time.  If the update misses, I would look at network/package-proxy issues

Comment: I've tried first apt-get update but i get error I described above. I don't use proxy and its true that I have slow internet but I tried few times at different time (even 3 am) but cannot update

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a temporary problem of slovenian mirror.

If persist (or if you hurry), try to replace with other repository.

- First, backup your sources.list:

  cd /etc/apt

  sudo cp sources.list sources.list_bk
- Second, edit your sourceslist:

  sudo nano sources.list

Replace "http://si.archive.ubuntu.com" occurrences with http://archive.ubuntu.com/

Let me know

Comment: sorry but even this server isn't working at all.